# Flickr photo search API not returning anything

Tags: php, api, curl, flickr

I tried to do a flickr search using cURL and Flickr API. When trying to print the response, it prints "1". What is wrong with my code?

```
$params = array(
    'api_key'   => 'b838e46f6e8eada6a62fac7e2b25ffcc',
    'method'    => 'flickr.photos.search',
    'format'    => 'php_serial',
    'text'  =>'cars'
);

$encoded_params = array();

foreach($params as $k => $v){
    $encoded_params[] = urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v);
}

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?'.implode('&', $encoded_params));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($file_contents);
curl_close($ch);

$rsp_obj = unserialize($file_contents);

//echo 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?'.implode('&', $encoded_params);
echo print_r($rsp_obj);
```

Comment: What do your get without `unserialize` on the cURL result? And use `var_dump` instead of echo to make the debug output.

Comment: @CBroe , rsp_obj= bool(false) / file_contents= bool(false), using var_dump.

Comment: Then var_dump what `curl_getinfo` has to say – any error messages from the API or something like that?

Comment: I used curl_errno and curl_error and this is what I get:
"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate".
I am using xampp local server.

Comment: Then try using the option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, so that cURL will not try to validate the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cURL can not verify the certificate of the remote site, then you can set the option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`, so that it will not try to do that.

This has of course some security implications – the remote site might not be who they pretend they are, but if you’re only doing a search that’s a rather minor concern, especially when you’re only testing locally for now. For a production app on a server you should maybe look into getting that fixed though, especially when you’ll be doing something that isn’t a pure search later on.